# Using mutate in dplyr with conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

*Edit: Reverting this back to the original text, which the responses below are based around. Thank you all for your help and apologies for changing the question after everyone so graciously helped me.*

I have a data frame which lists individuals, how many drinks they have had, what position they are in line, and whether they are eligible for a new drink.

```
dat <- data.frame(person = c("bill", "hank", "susy", "cliff", "betty"),
           total = c(3, 4, 5, 7, 8),
           position = c(1, 5, 3, 2, 4),
           eligible = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
```

The goal is that for anybody that is eligible for a new drink, we must add to their total number of drinks, the total number of drinks of the person one-behind them in line (e.g. to person 4's total, we add the total number of drinks of person 5). For anyone not eligible for a new drink, we keep their old total. The desired output is as follows:

```
person   total   position   eligible   new_total
bill     3       1          0          3    
hank     4       5          0          4
susy     5       3          1          13   
cliff    7       2          1          12   
betty    8       4          1          12
```

Does anyone know how I could do this using R and dplyr?

Thanks!

Comment: How do  you get the last value as 12 Can you show the calculation

Comment: Betty is eligible for a new drink. She is currently 4th in line and has had 8 drinks. Immediately behind her in line is Hank who has had 4 drinks. So 8 + 4 = 12

Comment: If two people have "the next ticket number", how do we know how much to add to the total? E.g., if Bill was eligible?

Comment: The lowest and highest ticket numbers will never be eligible. The end goal is slightly changed. I'm so sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That's great, but it doesn't answer my question. If Cliff had ticket 4 instead of 3, what  should you add to Susy's total?

Comment: The total of the highest ticket number, which is Hank (4), see editing text above. So sorry. I totally messed up writing this question :(

Comment: Yup. I screwed up royally. This is the pits of my Stack Overflow life. Apologies to everyone.

Comment: @DJC  It is okay.  I was just trying to convey the mesage that a well-crafted question would make others answer correctly.  But, if we change examples in the middle, then people lose theri interest

Answer (score 2):

You can use mutate and ifelse.
It helps to sort your list first.

```
dat <- dat %>%
      arrange(position) %>%
      mutate(new_total = ifelse(eligible, total+lead(total), total)) %>%
      arrange(total)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Brian. I'm not sure if this can be accomplished using arrange as number will repeat (see my edits above). Any idea how to do this without arrange?

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to create a sequence column with `rn`, `arrange` by 'position', then create the 'new_total' by adding the 'total' with `lead` of 'total' when the `eligible` is 1, and reorder based on the 'rn' column earlier created

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number())  %>%
  arrange(position) %>%  
  mutate(new_total = case_when(as.logical(eligible) ~
                  total + lead(total), TRUE ~ total)) %>% 
  arrange(rn) %>%
  select(-rn)
#   person total position eligible new_total
#1   bill     3        1        0         3
#2   hank     4        5        0         4
#3   susy     5        3        1        13
#4  cliff     7        2        1        12
#5  betty     8        4        1        12
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[order(position), new_total := total + shift(total, type = 'lead')
        ][eligible == 0, new_total := total][]
#   person total position eligible new_total
#1:   bill     3        1        0         3
#2:   hank     4        5        0         4
#3:   susy     5        3        1        13
#4:  cliff     7        2        1        12
#5:  betty     8        4        1        12
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. I've actually changed the example as this cannot be accomplished using 'arrange' as certain numbers will repeat. Any idea how to do it without arrange?

Answer (score 1):

Eligible is already 0/1, so you can use that to your benefit by just multiplying the total for the next person by the eligibility (or, alternatively, setting any true/false condition there if it's not that simple):

```
dat %>% arrange(position) %>% 
 mutate(new_total=total+eligible*(lead(total,default=0)))
  person total position eligible new_total
1   bill     3        1        0         3
2  cliff     7        2        1        12
3   susy     5        3        1        13
4  betty     8        4        1        12
5   hank     4        5        0         4
```

Just for fun, I compared the three solutions (although, with such a small dataset, this comparison may be inaccurate):

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
   iod 2.485992 2.694608  3.535079 2.921297  3.347454 28.47935   100
 brian 3.700652 4.037115  4.759614 4.268713  4.973099 16.12168   100
 arkun(dplyr) 8.173740 9.117087 10.194020 9.715270 10.730906 17.32028   100
```

Comment: Hi Iod, thanks for the quick response. I erred in writing my original example, this can't be accomplished using arrange/lead. I've updated my example to reflect this. Any idea how to fix using the new parameters?

Comment: data.table always wins, it's not fun. :)

Comment: Ok, then this is kind of misleading :=)

Comment: also, OP requested dplyr solution, so I have SOME justification. Added clarification above